# Do any halachot change for a eunuch?

Tags: halacha, medicine, sexuality, men-male

Do any halachot change if a man becomes (or is born) a eunuch? For example is he rabbinically allowed to listen to a woman's singing voice or be exposed to other sexually stimulating things if he is physically incapable of wasting seed?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes and no.

There are certain things are 'Objectively Forbidden' to be seen. This would apply regardless of any physical reaction to the stimulus. These would seemingly be forbidden to a eunuch as well.

Then there are things that are 'Subjectively Forbidden'. This goes on a case-by-case basis, depending on how the person viewing the stimulus reacts. Seemingly, one could argue that there are no cases of 'Subjectively Forbidden' materials for a eunuch.

A similar question was asked a while back, and I explained this answer more in depth [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61070/5346).

Comment: I never wanted to be one of those people who asked "why the downvote", but 2 already? Now I'm really curious. Can the downvoter(s) kindly explain why? While I naturally believe that my answer is correct (wouldn't have posted it otherwise), I'd be interested to hear why others disagree. Thanks!