# Is it forbidden to watch pornography?

Tags: halacha, sexuality, see-sight-vision-blind

I have heard that pornography is forbidden, but the reasons (most?) seem to be based upon statements in the Talmud that deal with situations where the potential for a sinful encounter may occur, from where is it known that even images are forbidden?

Comment: Even lewd thoughts about other woman are forbidden, and gazing at other women can obviously lead to such thoughts (and such thoughts are an inherent purpose of pornography). See here for starters: https://guardyoureyes.com/articles/windows-of-the-soul/item/day-7

Comment: Also, see this from Rambam's Mishneh Torah: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960669/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Twenty-One.htm

Comment: See links in http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17619

Comment: @Kordovero Seemed to get the main idea down about how thoughts themselves are forbidden, so I'll leave that to him to answer to get his well deserved fake internet points ;) I'll add one point myself: even if (theoretically) one could see certain materials without any reactions, some things are inherently forbidden to be seen, regardless of how one reacts to it. I feel weird quoting my own answer, but here's a link to another question where an answer I gave could address this question as well: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61070/5346

Answer (score -2):

Wouldn't pornography by definition be
"Ervah" prohibition?
Deuteronomy 23, 15

> כִּי֩ יְהֹוָ֨ה אֱלֹהֶ֜יךָ מִתְהַלֵּ֣ךְ | בְּקֶ֣רֶב מַֽחֲנֶ֗ךָ לְהַצִּֽילְךָ֙ וְלָתֵ֤ת אֹֽיְבֶ֨יךָ֙ לְפָנֶ֔יךָ וְהָיָ֥ה מַֽחֲנֶ֖יךָ קָד֑וֹשׁ וְלֹֽא-יִרְאֶ֤ה בְךָ֙ עֶרְוַ֣ת דָּבָ֔ר וְשָׁ֖ב מֵאַֽחֲרֶֽיךָ:‏
>
> For the LORD thy God walketh in the midst of thy camp, to deliver thee, and to give up thine enemies before thee; therefore shall thy camp be holy; that He see no unseemly thing in thee, and turn away from thee.

Comment: Perhaps? And if it were, then what?

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer.